# TableViewRow child is firing event on TableViewRow instead of its child iOS (Appcelerator Titanium)

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

On iOS click on TableViewRow child is firing event on TableViewRow instead of its child. How to fix it?

I have a tableView, which has click event attached to it and is filled with rows:

```
var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    populateData: populateData
});

tableView.addEventListener('click', tableViewClick);
```

Rows are simple and have views added:

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    type: 'row',
    height: 70,
    className: 'notes',
});

       var container = Ti.UI.createView({
            left: 15,
            width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
            touchEnabled: false,
        });

            var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                image: '/images/usuwanie.png',
                width: 35,
                height: 35,
                type: 'delete',
                id: data.id,
                searchType: data.type
            });

        container.add(image);

row.add(container);
```

Click action recognise which object fired the event:

```
var tableViewClick = function(e) {

    var type = e.source.type;
    var id = e.source.id;
    var searchType = e.source.searchType;
    var additionalText = e.source.additionalText;
    alert(e.source.type);
    switch(type) {
        case 'delete':
            deleteShopping(id,searchType);
            break;
        case 'edit': 
            editShopping(id, searchType, additionalText);
            break;
    }

};
```

It works perfectly on Android  - if I click the imageView, than imageView is a source of an event (alert returns 'delete' and 'deleteShopping' function is invoked).

On iOS the source is always the row (instead of ImageView) and alert returns 'row' and no function is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te reason was that parent container had 'touchEnabled' property set to false. If so than children will not fire event. On Android it will work. On iOS it won't. So it only takes to modify code like this:

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    type: 'row',
    height: 70,
    className: 'notes',
});

   var container = Ti.UI.createView({
        left: 15,
        width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        //touchEnabled: false,
        //touchEnabled above has to be commented
    });

        var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image: '/images/usuwanie.png',
            width: 35,
            height: 35,
            type: 'delete',
            id: data.id,
            searchType: data.type
        });

    container.add(image);

row.add(container);
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug is actually in Android. iOS is behaving as expected. Since there is no event listener on the image, it should not be the source. The event is bubbling up to the TableView since that is where the listener is attached.

To fix it, you need to add an eventListener on the image of every row.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that because but if we think that listener should be attached to direct source than we shouldn't add listener to tableview if we want to have tableViewRow as a source. This approach is supported by documentation as better and less demanding (one listener instead of one for every row).
I thought about doing changing the code as you say, but I have 2 images in a row which user can click. If I have 80 rows than I have 160 (sic!) listeners. It doesn't look good...

Comment: Unfortunately your answer is wrong or I missunderstood you. If I add eventListener to images, than it is still overrided by the listener added to row.

Comment: The tableView is an exception to most eventListeners in Titanium.  Usually you will need to add a listener to an object directly.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. These are really bad news, because I use TableView to avoid unnecesary listeners, memory consumption etc. and now I see I would do better if use scrollView instead.

Comment: TableView does have the advantage of reusing memory for rows and loading dynamically.  All good things if you have a lot of rows. I wouldn't worry about the memory overhead of adding eventListeners on every image. As long as you are using a named function (like image.addEventListener('click', deleteButtonClick); ) you'll be fine.

Comment: You may also need to set cancelBubble to true in your event handler for you image click event so the even doesn't bubble up to the TableView

Comment: OK. I managed it to work. TableView event is not overriding childs events now.